# Spring 3.1 with hibernate 4 can't use stored procedure with OracleTypes

Tags: oracle, spring, hibernate, stored-procedures, jdbc

Recently we upgraded from hibernate 3.5 to 4.1.7 as well as spring from 3.0.5 to 3.1.3. Hibernate is configured via jpa in spring so no changes is made.

After the upgrade, most of the stuff works fine but one function that uses stored procedure is broken with the following exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy188 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
>   at oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.setPhysicalConnectionOf(TypeDescriptor.java:829)
>           at oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.(TypeDescriptor.java:583)
>           at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.(ArrayDescriptor.java:224)
>           at org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlArrayValue.createTypeValue(SqlArrayValue.java:71)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractSqlTypeValue.setTypeValue(AbstractSqlTypeValue.java:58)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:281)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:217)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:128)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.CallableStatementCreatorFactory$CallableStatementCeatorImpl.createCallableStatement(CallableStatementCreatorFactory.java:212)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:1008)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.call(JdbcTemplate.java:1064)
>           at org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure.execute(StoredProcedure.java:144)

In debug mode, I found the `AbsructSqlTypeValue.setTypeValue()` method has the following implementation:

```
public final void setTypeValue(PreparedStatement ps, int paramIndex, int sqlType, String typeName)
        throws SQLException {

    Object value = createTypeValue(ps.getConnection(), sqlType, typeName);
    if (sqlType == TYPE_UNKNOWN) {
        ps.setObject(paramIndex, value);
    }
    else {
        ps.setObject(paramIndex, value, sqlType);
    }
}
```

The `ps.getConnection()` method here actually returns a new Hibernate 4 LogicalConnectionImpl which wraps around the real OracleConnection. And that's why the it throws the ClassCastException in Oracle driver.

The reason why it calls to oracle.SqlArrayValue is because the stored procedure takes list of longs as input parameter. When the input parameter is defined, we uses `OracleTypes.ARRAY` then while binding the values, we create a new `SqlArrayValue` object to wrap around the `Long[]`. I tried to use the generic `Types.Array` and `Long[]` directly but it didn't work either with the following exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: [Ljava.lang.Long;@337f5afe
>   at oracle.sql.ARRAY.toARRAY(ARRAY.java:187)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8782)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8278)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8877)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:4992)
>           at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.StatementProxyFactory.invoke(StatementProxyFactory.java:230)
>           at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.PreparedStatementProxyFactory.invoke(PreparedStatementProxyFactory.java:124)
>           at oracle.ucp.jdbc.proxy.CallableStatementProxyFactory.invoke(CallableStatementProxyFactory.java:101)
>           at $Proxy214.setObject(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)

I don't understand why the jdbcTemplate somehow uses the hibernate connection instead of the native `OracleConnection`, maybe there is some configuration somewhere can fix it magically?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause of it. The class that extends StoredProcedure didn't define the jdbcTemplate property so the default one is used which doesn't have nativeJdbcExtractor defined. After adding the jdbcTemplate dependency to refer to the one defined with org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor as nativeJdbcExtractor resolve the issue. I guess hibernate 3.5 with spring 3.0 doesn't have this issue since at that time the returned jdbc connection is already the OracleConnection.